# Median instead of mean distance of an underdetermined system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, median

I am given a number $N$ of 2D point pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ with corresponding values $(v_i,w_i)$. My task is now to find a linear matrix s.t.

$$ \begin{pmatrix} m_{x,1} & m_{y,1} & b_1 \\ m_{x,2} & m_{y,2} & b_2 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}x_i\\y_i \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}v_i\\w_i\end{pmatrix} $$

for all $i=1,\cdots, N$. Of course, with a high number of $N$, this system is underdetermined.

Using the normal equation, I can know find the mean matrix, such that overall the Euclidian mean is optimized.

**However**, I have a lot of outliers in my pairs that disturb the Euclidian mean.
Thus, I want to find the Euclidian *median* or something similar that is robust against outliers.

Any idea how I would do that?

Comment: IRLS, RANSAC,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression

Comment: Thanks! Can you elaborate a bit into an answer? I will likely accept it then :)

Comment: No need, if you got what you wanted